# Series with elements from an uncountable set

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $S$ be a given uncountable set in which all elements are positive real numbers.

Is it necessary that the set: { $\sum a_n |a_n\in S, a_i\neq a_j$ if $i\neq j$ } be unbounded? I mean can we find an uncountable set with positive elements such that the set of all series with distinct elements have an upper bound?

Comment: An uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ has uncountably many accumulation points. So there is a positive sequence of real numbers converging to some $x>0$. Sum of these numbers must be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $S$ is uncountable and $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable base, $S$ has uncountably many limit points in $S$. If $p \in S$ is one of them, take $p_n \in S$ all distinct such that $p_n \to p$, in particular we can find infinitely many close to $p$ such that the $\sum_n (p_n -p)$ absolutely converges in the reals, which implies that $\sum_n p_n$ diverges to $+\infty$.